# find the id of a post by its wordpress title

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a little problem with wordpress, I would like to update the date of a video post with an xlsx file.
I retrieve the data from my file and now I would like to retrieve the post id which is already created with the title  of the post (Title which I have in my xlsx file and which is the same as that of the post created).
I not sure how to do it  can you help me plz?

Comment: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_page_by_title/

Answer (score 0):

Use the following WordPress function

```
get_page_by_title('title', OBJECT, 'post');
```